# Database copying

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one database which is updated every minute, i should do some transactions using the DB.
But the same DB is used by many applications, so to do my transactions can i create a copy of the DB in my server. When the records are updated in the parent DB even the values in my DB should be updated. I would use the duplicated DB only to query records there will not be any updates/inserts.

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Why not use just one database? This is what databases are for... why add overhead?

Comment: What the heck - did it ever occur to you that sql server is perfectly capabile of handling multiple users or applications in ONE database? What you try to do there is making a taxi service by buying a new taxi for every trip, then complaining your costs are too high. Please learn how databases operate. Ask your programming lead.

Comment: may be a [snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) ?